# MTAudioProcessingTap kills mediaserverd at breakpoints

Tags: ios, avfoundation

When using AVPlayer with MTAudioProcessingTap, stopping at a breakpoint anywhere in the application, on any thread, will cause mediaserverd to die temporarily.

This can be observed by setting a breakpoint anywhere in Apple's sample app. [AudioTapProcessor]

> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html

For example, you can set it in the updateCenterFrequencySliderValue: method in MYSettingsViewController.m. (I also have an even smaller sample app I can post if it's helpful.)

This error message usually only appears in the device's Console log (viewable in Organizer), but sometimes also appears in the app's debugger log:

```
    <Error>: 17:48:04.833 ERROR:     [0x28c0000] 75: AudioQueueProcessingTapGetSourceAudio posting message to kill mediaserverd (45)
```

Playback usually resumes several seconds after continuing past the breakpoint. The `AVAudioSessionMediaServicesWereResetNotification` is not posted.

Is this expected behavior, or does it indicate a problem? Is there any way to avoid it? If you are using MTAudioProcessingTap and regularly encounter this, has it been an issue for your development or debugging process?

(I'd also be interested in any feedback on whether MTAudioProcessingTap is ready for primetime generally, since it's a relatively new and lightly documented component.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever find out?